# Does UIImageView release resources when not in view?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimageview

Does `UIImageView` automatically release image resources when it isn't in view? And perhaps when the app gets a memory warning?

If not, I'm considering writing a subclass (e.g. `SmartReleaseImageView`) that does so, to be used in particular situations where this would be beneficial. I was thinking of behaviour along these lines:

- When `SmartReleaseImageView` receives `setImage` message, it registers itself with a manager e.g. `SmartReleaseImageViewManager`.
- When app gets a memory warning, `SmartReleaseImageViewManager` loops through all its `SmartReleaseImageViews` and checks whether any of them aren't added to a superview, or checks whether any of them have a frame that is culled due to being outside of the bounds of the main window.
- When `SmartReleaseImageView` detects that it has come into view and has been released, it loads the image again. So perhaps, it would need to have a method like `setImageURL` rather than `setImage` in the first place.

Is this kind of behaviour already built into `UIImageView`? Or does it exist in a 3rd party version anywhere? Or is there a problem with idea?

(I'm writing a UIImageView-heavy app, and it would be nice to have a global catch-all solution that would help with the memory situation, rather than adding lots of extra code to my `UIViewControllers`.)

***EDIT***: Answers so far suggest that `UIViewController` should be responsible. This is true, and I guess my particular case is atypical. In my case, the UIViewController can contain a lot of custom views (with their own hierarchy) that it doesn't necessarily know the structure of, and which go in and out of view frequently. So, it's difficult for it to know when to release its resources. But yes, perhaps I should find a way for it to deal with the problem itself...

Comment: It sounds a little as if you were addressing the issue from the wrong side. A UIViewController usually unloads its views as soon as memory gets tight - to me, it seems as if you should simply rely on those mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you actually have this automatic management implemented in the UIViewController. Since UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, your view controller should be able to manage it automatically.

> Memory Management
>
> Memory is a critical resource in iOS, and view controllers provide
>   built-in support for reducing their memory footprint at critical
>   times. The UIViewController class provides some automatic handling of
>   low-memory conditions through its didReceiveMemoryWarning method,
>   which releases unneeded memory. Prior to iOS 3.0, this method was the
>   only way to release additional memory associated with your custom view
>   controller class but in iOS 3.0 and later, the viewDidUnload method
>   may be a more appropriate place for most needs.
>
> When a low-memory warning occurs, the UIViewController class purges
>   its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If
>   this happens, it also calls the viewDidUnload method to give your code
>   a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated
>   with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded with the nib file,
>   objects created in your viewDidLoad method, and objects created lazily
>   at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. Typically, if your view
>   controller contains outlets (properties or raw variables that contain
>   the IBOutlet keyword), you should use the viewDidUnload method to
>   relinquish ownership of those outlets or any other view-related data
>   that you no longer need.

source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
`UIImageView` does not release resources, never.
But all your views (including `UIImageView`) are released when the system needs more memory. Note that you have to release your views in `[UIViewController viewDidUnload]`.

Edit:
Unfortunately, it doesn't work when the controller is not displayed. It that case I suggest to purge the components manually in `viewDidDissappear` (call `viewDidUnload` manually and remove components from the view hierarchy).

Anyway, this won't help if one view controller has too many images in its hierarchy. In this case I would recommend to create a set of `UIImageView`s and reuse them, in the same way as `UITableView` reuses its cells.

Comment: Does `viewDidUnload` get called even when the `UIViewController` is the current/active view controller?